# my layout elements are not in place

Tags: android, layout, apk

I have a grid and a TextView in a layout, on top I have a EditText to copy text, when you copy the text in a cell the keyboard appears and unconfigures me my whole layout, as do the keyboard to appear all elements are in place?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PLU"
    android:id="@+id/textView_plu"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="43dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText_plu"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_plu"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView_plu"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView_plu"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ubic"
    android:id="@+id/textView_ubic"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_plu"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_plu"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView_plu" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText_ubic"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_ubic"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_plu"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText_plu" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_opciones"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView_plu"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText_plu"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText_plu" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cant"
    android:id="@+id/textView_cant"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_ubic"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_ubic"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView_ubic" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="GRP"
    android:id="@+id/textView_grp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_cant"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_cant"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView_cant" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText_cant"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView_grp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_ubic"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText_ubic" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText_grp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_grp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_cant"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText_cant" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_opcionesvisibles"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView_cant"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText_cant"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText_cant" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Num"
    android:id="@+id/textView_num"
    android:layout_above="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView_cant"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView_cant"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Ubic"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView_num"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Ref"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="PLU"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Desc"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to copy the text from the `TextView`, why don't set the attribute `android:textIsSelectable` to true and remove the `EditText` completely?